# Passing arguments to redirect

Tags: mojolicious

How do I pass arguments to redirect and use that in the template, like we do it in the render

```
$self->render(controller => 'controller', action => 'action', message => "my message");
```

similarly,

```
$self->redirect_to(controller => 'controller', action => 'action', message => "my message");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-2.60/lib/Mojolicious/Controller.pm#redirect_to)
Also, note that you can not pass arguments which will be directly used in the template since you force the client(browser) to make a new request.
on the next request the "arguments"/ parameters will be in $c->req->params() and you can do whatever you wish with them.